# Critical Edition of Sanskrit Text

Tags: critical

I Want to make a Critical Edition of a Sanskrit text with five sections including critical apparatus. I have prepared a layout on MS Word. But I want to do it on Latex. I'm confused about where to start. Can anybody please help me with a simple sample file having these sections mentioned in the picture?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You can use `mdframed` or `tcolorbox` packages. But your example is an algorithm?

Comment: No Sir. It's just simple text.

Comment: Have you searched the packages that have I indicated?

Comment: Yes. They actually deal with boxes, what I understood. I was talking about critical apparatuses and notes. I can manage the apparatus using \edtext{⟨lemma⟩}{⟨commands⟩}. But I need to add more sections that follow the original text's line numerals. And also, the section-divider lines with the text in the middle of it.

Comment: Have you looked at the `reledmac` package which is designed for this sort of thin?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to do it with reledmac. But I could not find any command for the divider lines with text in the middle of it.